# Is starting a socket.io server inside a get request ok to do?

Tags: node.js, session, socket.io

New to socket.io and wanted to know if starting a socket server inside of a get request is ok to do if I want to match a session id (http request) with a socket id?

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  res.render('index.ejs')


  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(socket)
  });


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will attach a *additional* listener for every request that is made, so it is probably not such a good idea. All previous listeners for `io.on('connection', ...)` will be executed when the next socket.io connection is made.